# Webkit only applies dynamic loaded css styles (via ajax) on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

maybe you can get me in the right direction, this bothers me for a long time now. In my content editor (javascript + jquery) you can change fonts on the fly. If you change a font in the editor it will send an ajax request to get the css file with the font and the styles and then append it to the head section. This works perfectly in mozilla and IE but has a bit of a downside in webkit browsers. If i change the font 10 times, most (but not all) of the time i have to resize the browser (just a few pixel) so the styles gets applied.

Any Idea how to force it that the styles get applied? I tried to trigger the resize event but that was obviously a noob fail from me. ;)

Thanks a lot! (and as always sorry for my bad 'germanish' english)

Answer (score 0):

Really embarrasing. This is the way i start my editor. Thanks to the 'html,body' selector my editor gets initialised twice! That's caused the problems with chrome.

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 0, function () {
    $('#editor').fadeIn(300, function() {
        /* init editor */
        editor.init();
    });
});
```